# Recursive Path finding error

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

I'm working on an exercise where given a set of connections between two points (ie. 12 is a connection between 1 and 2 ect.). I decided to tackle the approach recursively in order to have it systematically check every path and return when it finds one that hits every node and starts  and ends with one.

However upon debugging this it seems that as I pass down the adjMatrix further into the recursion it's also editing the upper levels and causing it not to search any further as it goes back up the tree. I think it has something to when I set `newMatrix = adjMatrix`, but I'm not exactly sure.

```
def checkio(teleports_string):
    #return any route from 1 to 1 over all points
    firstnode, secondnode, size = 0, 0, 8

    #Makes the adjacency matrix
    adjMatrix = [[0 for i in range(size)] for j in range(size)]

    for x in teleports_string:
        #Assigns Variables
        if firstnode == 0 and x != ",":
            #print("Node1:" + x)
            firstnode = x
        elif secondnode == 0 and x != ",":
            #print("Node2:" + x)
            secondnode = x
        #Marks connections
        if firstnode != 0 and secondnode != 0:
            adjMatrix[int(firstnode) - 1][int(secondnode) - 1] = 1
            adjMatrix[int(secondnode) - 1][int(firstnode) - 1] = 1
            firstnode, secondnode = 0, 0
    print(adjMatrix)

    return findPath(adjMatrix, 1, "1")


def findPath(adjMatrix, currentnode, currentpath):
    if isFinished(currentpath):
        return currentpath

    for x in range(0, 8):
        if adjMatrix[currentnode - 1][x] == 1:
            print(currentpath + "+" + str(x+1))
            newMatrix = adjMatrix
            newMatrix[currentnode - 1][x] = 0
            newMatrix[x][currentnode - 1] = 0
            temp = currentpath
            temp += str(x+1)
            newpath = findPath(newMatrix, x+1,temp)
            print(newpath)
            if isFinished(newpath):
                 print ("Returning: " + newpath)
                 return newpath
    return ""


def isFinished(currentpath):
    #Checks if node 1 is hit at least twice and each other node is hit at least once
    if currentpath == "":
        return False

    for i in range(1, 9):
        if i == 1 and currentpath.count(str(i)) < 2:
            return False
        elif currentpath.count(str(i)) < 1:
            return False
    #Checks if it starts and ends with 1
    if not currentpath.startswith(str(1)) or not currentpath.endswith(str(1)):
        return False
    return True

#This part is using only for self-testing
if __name__ == "__main__":
    def check_solution(func, teleports_str):
        route = func(teleports_str)
        teleports_map = [tuple(sorted([int(x), int(y)])) for x, y in teleports_str.split(",")]
        if route[0] != '1' or route[-1] != '1':
            print("The path must start and end at 1")
            return False
        ch_route = route[0]
        for i in range(len(route) - 1):
            teleport = tuple(sorted([int(route[i]), int(route[i + 1])]))
            if not teleport in teleports_map:
                print("No way from {0} to {1}".format(route[i], route[i + 1]))
                return False
            teleports_map.remove(teleport)
            ch_route += route[i + 1]
        for s in range(1, 9):
            if not str(s) in ch_route:
                print("You forgot about {0}".format(s))
                return False
        return True

    assert check_solution(checkio, "13,14,23,25,34,35,47,56,58,76,68"), "Fourth"
```

Comment: `newMatrix = adjMatrix` **does not** create a new matrix. Both names now refer to *the same object*. See e.g. [this article](http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html#python-has-names). You need to make a [`deepcopy`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line

```
newMatrix = adjMatrix
```

merely creates another reference to your list. You'll need to actually create a *new* list object. As this is a matrix, do so for the contents:

```
newMatrix = [row[:] for row in adjMatrix]
```

This creates a new list of copies of your nested lists.

Comment: Thanks!I'm new to Python and had a feeling that this was the issue, but wasn't exactly sure how to phrase it for Google searches. I'll test it now.